Why did the 1976 Super DC Calendar pick February 19 as Bruce Wayne's birthday?
Why did the 1976 Super DC Calendar pick February 19 as Bruce Wayne's birthday?
What's the significance? I'm just trying to find out if it's an homage to a specific event or person's date.
So what is the story behind that date?

https://www.mtv.com/news/xxfa1g/batman-75th-anniversary-birthday-date it's also moved around a fair bit.

FWIW, the same date is apparently used in Batman Family Vol 1 11 and the letter column of Detective Comics #494.

Thanks for your help but dc 1976 calendar predates the comics you directed me to
